# Null props using ReactJS promise redux middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

This is my Dashboard.js using react redux promise middleware. Fetching data from facebook then pass that to dispatch action. I want to ask why im getting null value on this.props.brandsInformation?

Is there a way for me to access the data in the componentDidMount function()?

Any help would greatly appreciated seems a roadblock for me here.

```
    /* global FB */

import React from 'react';
import { cyan600, pink600, purple600, orange600 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import Assessment from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/assessment';
import Face from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/face';
import ThumbUp from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/thumb-up';
import ShoppingCart from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/shopping-cart';
import InfoBox from '../components/dashboard/InfoBox';
import NewOrders from '../components/dashboard/NewOrders';
import MonthlySales from '../components/dashboard/MonthlySales';
import BrowserUsage from '../components/dashboard/BrowserUsage';
import RecentlyProducts from '../components/dashboard/RecentlyProducts';
import globalStyles from '../styles';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import LeftDrawer from '../components/LeftDrawer';
import NavbarComponent from './Navbar';
import withWidth, { LARGE, SMALL } from 'material-ui/utils/withWidth';
import ThemeDefault from '../theme-default';
import Data from '../data';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { socialActions } from '../_actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import FacebookReduxLogin from 'facebook-login-redux-react';


class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    this.getUserInformation = this.getUserInformation.bind(this);

  }


  login(response) {
    this.props.actions.getLoginStatus(response.status);
  }
  logout(response) {
    this.props.actions.getLoginStatus(response.status);
    this.props.actions.getUserInformation(null);
    this.props.actions.getBrandInformation(null);

  }


  getUserInformation() {

    if (this.props.facebookLogin.isConnected && !this.props.userInformation) {
      FB.api('/me', 'GET', { fields: 'id,name,email' },
        userInformation => {
          this.props.actions.getUserInformation(userInformation).then(function(user) {
          });
        }
      );
      FB.api('/me/accounts', 'GET',
        brandInformation => {
          this.props.actions.getBrandInformation(brandInformation).then(function(brands) {
          });
        }
      );
    }


  }

  handleDrawer(bool) {
    this.setState({ open: bool });
  }

    componentDidMount() {
       //WHy is this null? how can i process the promise data and put it on this variable
       console.log(this.props.brandInformation)
  }

  render() {
    const navDrawerOpen = this.state.open;
    const paddingLeftDrawerOpen = 236;
    const { id, name, email } = this.props.userInformation || { id: null, name: null, email: null };
    this.getUserInformation();
    const styles = {
      container: {
        margin: '80px 20px 20px 15px',
        paddingLeft: navDrawerOpen && this.props.width !== SMALL ? paddingLeftDrawerOpen : 0

      }
    };
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={ThemeDefault}>

        <div>
            <NavbarComponent handleDrawer={this.handleDrawer.bind(this)}/>
              <div style={styles.container}>
                <div>
                  <h3 style={globalStyles.navigation}>Application / Dashboard</h3>

                        <FacebookReduxLogin
                          appId='1413936068720959'
                          verbose={false}
                          version={'v2.10'}
                          onWillMount={this.login}
                          onLoginEvent={this.login}
                          onLogoutEvent={this.logout}
                          onClick={() => this.props.actions.startFetching()}
                        />

                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>

    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state)
  return {
    userInformation: state.userInformation,
    brandInformation: state.brandInformation,
    facebookLogin: state.facebookLogin
  };

}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(socialActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashboardPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the data before it's loaded. That's why you're getting null prop on the first render. Your component lifecycle looks like this:

1. Component is constructed, async request is sent to facebook for data.
2. Component is rendered - at this time facebook request is not yet completed, so there is no data and you're getting null prop.
3. Facebook request is completed and your actions are dispatched.
4. Redux state is changed, which triggers re-render of your component, this time with correct data.

There's not much you can do about it - that's how async requests work. The only option you have is something like this, probably encapsulated in some kind of higher level component:

```
render() {
    if(null === this.props.userInformation || null === this.props.brandInformation) {
        return <span>Still loading data...</span>;
    } else {
        // render what you want here
    }
}
```